# set the right encoding for file name from database with speical character

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters, php-ziparchive

I am trying to create file with data from my database. And I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to convert to the right encoding for windows file name.

The database is in `latin1_german2_ci`, which contains german character like ä,ö,ü. Now I need to get data from the database and construct a file from it.
for exampe I got `$name` from database with `$name = "zäng" and "$id = "123"`

first:

```
$folder_name = $id . ' - ' . $name;
mkdir($folder_name);
$file_name = $folder_name . '/' . $id;
file_put_contents($file_name . '.lic', $contents);
```

this create the folder `123 - zäng`, which is correct. and some files are added to the folder like `123.lic, 123.rom`...

Next Step, I want to create a zip file with same name:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = $folder_name . '.zip';
$zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)
// to confirm its working, add an empty folder to the zip
$zip->addEmptyDir("testfolder");
```

this create a file names `123 - zäng.zip` with subfolder `testfolder`. works perfectly too.
Now it happens something strange, I have to create a subfolder with the same name as the zip-file, and add some files to the subfolder. I try to achieve this with `addFile`:

```
$zip->addFile($file_name . '.lic', $folder_name . '/' . $id . '.lic');
```

which should create something like this:

```
123 - zäng.zip/123 - zäng/123.lic
```

but instead, the folder I created in zip file got the name `RI15120201 - zõng`, the special character is wrong.  In `ZipArchive`-API, someone said

> ZipArchive uses IBM850 encoding for filenames (localname). For filenames with special characters such as (é) é which appears at 0xE9 in the ISO-8859-1, it is at 0x82 in IBM850. I had to call iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'IBM850', 'Québec') to get correct file names.

additionally, I found out that

> latin1 (cp1252 West European) collations:
>
> latin1_bin
>
> latin1_danish_ci
>
> latin1_german1_ci
>
> latin1_german2_ci

so I changed the code:

```
iconv('cp1252', 'ibm850', $name);
$folder_name = $id . ' - ' . $name;
mkdir($folder_name);
$file_name = $folder_name . '/' . $id;
file_put_contents($file_name . '.lic', $contents);
```

but it didn't change anything. What am I missing? And why are `mkdir` and `$zip->open` working without converting the encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you don't assign new value which is returned by iconv()

Change

```
iconv('cp1252', 'ibm850', $name);
```

to

```
$name = iconv('cp1252', 'ibm850', $name);
```

You'll probably need to do the same with $contents

Comment: oh my god, that's it.... `mkdir` and `$zip->open` gives the wrong name though, so I moved the line right after the `$zip = new ZipArchive` line, it works now perfectly! Thank you very much. I guess `mkdir` and `$zip->open` work with "normal" encoding?

Comment: I just find it strange that ZipArchive::open() works normal, but ZipArchive::addFile needs special encoding... took me hours to figure that out in the first place...